# How can I have multiple conditions in a while statement? (c++)

Tags: c++, while-loop

Is it possible to have three conditions in a while statement?

for example:

```
cout << "\n\nHow would you like your parcel shipped?\n (please type standard, express"
    " or same day)" << endl;
cin >> method;
while (method != ("standard" && "express" && "same day"))
{
    cout << "invalid input: please follow the instructions carefully.." << endl;
    cout << "\n\nHow would you like your parcel shipped?\n (please type 'standard',"
        " 'express' or 'same day')" << endl;
    cin >> method;
}
```

The reason I ask is that when I run this code, it goes into an infinite loop and I am having trouble understanding why.

Comment: The `&&` operators here have pointers to strings as arguments.

Comment: As the answers come in, think about your expression `("standard" && "express" && "same day")` and what value is produced by that expression.

Comment: _"it goes into an infinite loop and I am having trouble understanding why."_ Well, none of the current answers here exlains this correctly yet. (and that one that really attempted on this deleted their answer :-( ).

Comment: What is `method`? A `char[*]`, `char*`, `std::string`?

Comment: As an aside, don't be so `endl`-happy. In most cases, a standard newline is enough, simpler, and more performant.

Comment: 'method' was type boolean, and therein lie my problem.  I was trying to use it like a string when comparing it to a literal.  Thanks for pointing that out Alf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is just that in

```
method != ("standard" && "express" && "same day")
```

the `&&` operator is applied to pointers to characters, which are converted to `bool` as if they were compared to nullpointers (this is the general conversion to `bool` for any basic value *v*, namely *v* `!= 0`). Since they're all non-null the result of the parenthesis part is `true`. Comparing that to `method` via `!=` is likely to not compile, depending on the type of `method`.

**If** `method` is a `std::string` …

then you can compare it directly to string literals, and write the condition as

```
not (method == "standard" or method == "express" or method == "same day")
```

but do note that this won't work if `method` is a raw array (also note: for Visual C++ include `<iso646.h>`, e.g. via forced include, in order to make standard `not` compile).

A generally better way to express the condition is to use a set of values, and check for membership in that set.

Now, the code shown,

```
cout << "\n\nHow would you like your parcel shipped?\n (please type standard, express or same day)" << endl;
cin >> method;
while (method != ("standard" && "express" && "same day"))
{
    cout << "invalid input: please follow the instructions carefully.." << endl;
    cout << "\n\nHow would you like your parcel shipped?\n (please type 'standard', 'express' or 'same day')" << endl;
    cin >> method;
}
```

is known as a **loop and a half**, repeating some of the code at the end of the loop, before the loop.

Still assuming that `method` is a `std::string`, you can restructure it like this:

```
for( ;; )
{
    cout << "\n\nHow would you like your parcel shipped?\n (please type 'standard', 'express' or 'same day')" << endl;
    cin >> method;
    if( method == "standard" or method == "express" or method == "same day" )
    {
        break;
    }
    cout << "invalid input: please follow the instructions carefully.." << endl;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, `while(true)` might be easiert to understand to a beginner than `for (;;)`

Answer (score 5):

```
while (method != "standard" && method != "express" && method != "same day")
```

Comment: This answer could have been better if you explained what his original expression evaluates to.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (method != ("standard" && "express" && "same day")) { /* ... */ }
```

All those string literals evaluate to `true` when meeting the boolean, because they are not `NULL` after array decay (which results in a pointer to their first element) (`NULL` is guaranteed to be different from the address of any object).

Thus, the loop is equivalent to:

```
while (method != true) { /* ... */ }
```

What I don't quite get is why your compiler does not complain loudly on that comparison, irrespective of `method` being a `char*`, `char[]` or `std::string`.
Maybe you should ask for standard-compliance and warnings?
`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++14` is a good start.

On coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c2c05950274388e

If you want to fix your code, make each comparison for itself (use `strcmp` for `char*` or `char[]`, simple comparison for `std::string`), and combine the results with boolean operators (`&&` `||` `!`).

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you have shown it, no. Each condition must be tested individually:

```
while ((method != "standard") && (method != "express") && (method != "same day"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible; you just need to do it right:

```
while (method != "standard" && method != "express" && method != "same day")
{
    // do whatever 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
cout << "\n\nHow would you like your parcel shipped?\n (please type standard, express or same day)" << endl;
cin >> method;
while (method != "standard" && method != "express" && method != "same day")
{
    cout << "invalid input: please follow the instructions carefully.." << endl;
    cout << "\n\nHow would you like your parcel shipped?\n (please type 'standard', 'express' or 'same day')" << endl;
    cin >> method;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works:

```
 while (condition && condition && condition) { }
```

Theoratically, you can chain as many conditions as you'd like/need.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (method != "standard" && method != "express" && method != "same day")
```